# MSK modulation and doppler shift

Tags: digital-communications

I have a question about MSK modulation and the influence of doppler shift on this modulation.

For simplicity, suppose we consider the MSK signal in baseband: $s(t)=Ae^{j(d_k\frac{\pi t}{2T}+\phi_k)}$ where $T$ is the $k$-th bit period an $\phi_k$ the initial phase for the $k$-th bit.

With Doppler shift in baseband, we have: $x(t)=s((1-a)t)e^{-j2 \pi f_d t}=s(t)e^{-j(d_k \frac{\pi a t}{2T}+2 \pi f_d t})=s(t).\lambda(t)$ with $a=\frac{v}{c}$, $v$ is the speed, $c$ the wave speed and $f_d=af_c$, $f_c$ the carrier frequency.

This is my questions:

1)Is it necessary to compensate for the doppler shift in the demodulation of the signal?

2)How to demodulate baseband signal?